# Google Apps script: Trigger does not work for e-mails to be sent out

Tags: email, google-apps-script, triggers

I am writing a code that aims to inform me via e-mail if a value on a website changes. In order to do so, I use 4 functions:

- function one executes functions 2-4
- function 2 is a scraper
- function 3 writes the data in a new line in a spreadsheet
- function 4 compares the newly written line and sends out an e-mail if the new line is different from the one before.

Function one is triggered automatically every 5 minutes. The spreadsheet shows that the trigger works fine for function two and three (scrape and save the data to the spreadsheet), every five minutes the spreadsheet is being updated. I do not, however, get an e-mail when something changes.

When I execute function one manually, it works, including e-mails being send out if the data changed. I tried to add an additional trigger to just execute the function that compares the data and sends an e-mail. That, however, also did not lead to e-mails being sent to me.

If it matters: The data change about once an hour. I however, want to get informed asap, hence the frequent checks

Do you have any idea, why the trigger for sending out the e-mails does not work and do you have any solution for me?

Thanks in advance!

```
  function scrape_save_send(){
  getData();
  saveData();
  SendEmail();
}

function getData() { // works just fine, code cut to make it not too long
[...]
}

function saveData() {         // works fine both automatically and manually
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
 sheet.appendRow([new Date(), getData()]);
 var lrow = sheet.getLastRow();
 sheet.getRange(lrow,3).setFormula('=SPLIT(B'+lrow+'; "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz=<>- /")')       // workaround to extract a number from the scraped content
}

function SendEmail() {                         // works just fine if executed manually
  Utilities.sleep(2000)                        // delays the check
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  if (sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()-1,2).getValue() === sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),2).getValue()) {
    Logger.log('equal');
  } else {
   var invest = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),8).getValue();
    MailApp.sendEmail("ab@gmail.com", invest + "blablabla", "blablabla");
   // Logger.log('not equal');
  }
  }
```

Comment: I found the solution: the getUi()-function apparently caused the problem. Since I don't need it (it was left over from an old function) I deleted it, the script now works automatically. 

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `MailApp` to `GmailApp` in the last line of `SendEmail()` function.

Comment: Try putting a flush() between sendData and SendEmail().

Comment: The OP is using the wrong class. its actually GmailApp and not MailApp.

Comment: If that was the case, the function also should not work manually, I assume.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: the getUi()-function apparently caused the problem. Some research showed me that the getUi()-function only works when the according sheet is opened.

Since I don't need the function (it was left over from an old function) I deleted it, the script now works automatically. Thanks!